# Get the value of a sub-child element by a sub-child value of JSON response using Groovy

Tags: json, groovy

I have the following Groovy script to get the values from the JSON response.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def inputFile = new File("C:\\Apps\\test.txt")
JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper()
Map parsedJson = slurper.parseText(inputFile.text)
println parsedJson.value.nodes.find{it.sessionId = '8f667c8556fc7178c427ee4dd64d2d16'}.uri
```

my JSON response is similar to this

```json
{
"value": {
"ready": true,
"message": "test ready.",
"nodes": [
{
"id": "c77a97c2-e510-4e24-8916-2c3962ccdec9",
"uri": "http://test001:444",
"maxSessions": 2,
"heartbeatPeriod": 60000,
"availability": "UP",
"version": "4.1.1 (revision e8fcc2cecf)",
"slots": [
{
"id": {
"hostId": "c77a97c2-e510-4e24-8916-2c3962ccdec9",
"id": "3e659215-2e3c-48e2-9b02-0c986399a8c7"
},
"lastStarted": "2022-01-07T19:45:40.320Z",
"session": null,
},
{
"id": {
"hostId": "c77a97c2-e510-4e24-8916-2c3962ccdec9",
"id": "3985c443-599e-48c3-a34c-9b1cdb8f30ab"
},
"lastStarted": "2022-01-07T19:41:03.616Z",
"session": {
"capabilities": {
"acceptInsecureCerts": false,
"browserName": "chrome",
"browserVersion": "97.0.4692.71",
"chrome": {
"chromedriverVersion": "97.0.4692.36 (747e0a0f19c13ca6ee136200f5b097448ae4892f-refs/branch-heads/4692@{#607})",
"userDataDir": "C:\\Users\\pas_test\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\scoped_dir7776_2131041583"
},
"goog:chromeOptions": {
"debuggerAddress": "localhost:50606"
},
"networkConnectionEnabled": false,
"pageLoadStrategy": "normal",
"platformName": "windows",
"proxy": {
"proxyType": "DIRECT"
},
"se:cdp": "ws://10.177.101.17:4444/session/880eb6b2ee4dbf55f23b9a880b61d03c/se/cdp",
"se:cdpVersion": "97.0.4692.71",
"setWindowRect": true,
"strictFileInteractability": false,
"timeouts": {
"implicit": 0,
"pageLoad": 300000,
"script": 30000
},
"unhandledPromptBehavior": "dismiss and notify",
"webauthn:extension:credBlob": true,
"webauthn:extension:largeBlob": true,
"webauthn:virtualAuthenticators": true
},
"sessionId": "880eb6b2ee4dbf55f23b9a880b61d03c",
"start": "2022-01-07T19:41:03.616Z",
"stereotype": {
"browserName": "chrome",
"platformName": "WIN10"
},
"uri": "http://test001:444"
},
"stereotype": {
"browserName": "chrome",
"platformName": "WIN10"
}
}
]
},
{
"id": "8ee675f0-bb43-49c9-a566-26e014031c74",
"uri": "http://test031:444",
"maxSessions": 2,
"osInfo": {
"arch": "amd64",
"name": "Windows 10",
"version": "10.0"
},
"heartbeatPeriod": 60000,
"availability": "UP",
"version": "4.1.1 (revision e8fcc2cecf)",
"slots": [
{
"id": {
"hostId": "8ee675f0-bb43-49c9-a566-26e014031c74",
"id": "67c65e9e-55df-4a00-a132-55969bb56d48"
},
"lastStarted": "2022-01-07T19:50:21.931Z",
"session": null,
"stereotype": {
"browserName": "chrome",
"platformName": "WIN10"
}
},
{
"id": {
"hostId": "8ee675f0-bb43-49c9-a566-26e014031c74",
"id": "56831fd6-c943-4af9-ba21-f92661e5d803"
},
"lastStarted": "2022-01-07T19:49:41.985Z",
"session": null,
"stereotype": {
"browserName": "chrome",
"platformName": "WIN10"
}
}
]
},
{
"id": "6273efa7-a41a-42ee-9a9c-1eb853f5bfdb",
"uri": "http://test017:444",
"maxSessions": 2,
"osInfo": {
"arch": "amd64",
"name": "Windows 10",
"version": "10.0"
},
"heartbeatPeriod": 60000,
"availability": "UP",
"version": "4.1.1 (revision e8fcc2cecf)",
"slots": [
{
"id": {
"hostId": "6273efa7-a41a-42ee-9a9c-1eb853f5bfdb",
"id": "0e5a15b6-f947-46fe-a022-20987591accf"
},
"lastStarted": "2022-01-07T19:44:56.621Z",
"session": null,
"stereotype": {
"browserName": "chrome",
"platformName": "WIN10"
}
},
{
"id": {
"hostId": "6273efa7-a41a-42ee-9a9c-1eb853f5bfdb",
"id": "eb7787aa-f3b1-40b4-9776-a882aa4824d2"
},
"lastStarted": "2022-01-07T19:51:02.814Z",
"session": {
"capabilities": {
"acceptInsecureCerts": false,
"browserName": "chrome",
"browserVersion": "96.0.4664.110",
"chrome": {
"chromedriverVersion": "96.0.4664.35 (8df3babf8da8faa8aacb78f4848ef66a93b4944b-refs/branch-heads/4664@{#680})",
"userDataDir": "C:\\Users\\pas_test\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\scoped_dir5512_1146555922"
},
"goog:chromeOptions": {
"debuggerAddress": "localhost:50830"
},
"networkConnectionEnabled": false,
"pageLoadStrategy": "normal",
"platformName": "windows",
"proxy": {
"proxyType": "DIRECT"
},
"se:cdp": "ws://10.177.101.245:4444/session/8f667c8556fc7178c427ee4dd64d2d16/se/cdp",
"se:cdpVersion": "96.0.4664.110",
"setWindowRect": true,
"strictFileInteractability": false,
"timeouts": {
"implicit": 0,
"pageLoad": 300000,
"script": 30000
},
"unhandledPromptBehavior": "dismiss and notify",
"webauthn:extension:credBlob": true,
"webauthn:extension:largeBlob": true,
"webauthn:virtualAuthenticators": true
},
"sessionId": "8f667c8556fc7178c427ee4dd64d2d16",
"uri": "http://test017:444"
},
}
]
}
]
}
}
```

I want to get the corresponding 'uri' for the given sessionId("sessionId": "8f667c8556fc7178c427ee4dd64d2d16",). But I am always getting the wrong uri as output i.e my code always returning first uri i.e **http://test001:444** instead of **http://test017:444**

please correct me what I am doing wrong here ? Thanks.

Comment: You are using `=` instead of `==` in your predicate.

Comment: @cfrick, when I use ```==``` instead of ```=```, its throwing me: ```java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'uri' on null object```

Comment: `...value.nodes*.slots*.session*.find{ it?.sessionId == '8f667c8556fc7178c427ee4dd64d2d16' }.uri`

Comment: @cfrick You are awesome!!! That worked for me. Thanks very much. You saved my day.